# Using larger font with Powerline

Tags: spacemacs, powerline

I've just switched to using spacemacs with powerline.  I'm trying to make the font larger (my eyes are not as good as they used to be).  But when I do, the powerline separator gets screwed up.  Is there anyway to scale that up as well?

I've update size to 16 (from 13) and changed powerline-scale to 0.8 (from 1.1) to try and counteract the size problem.

```
dotspacemacs-default-font '("Source Code Pro"
                               :size 16
                               :weight normal
                               :width normal
                               :powerline-scale 0.8)
```

This is what I get
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I misunderstood how the `:powerline-scale` parameter works.  To use with a larger font, I need to make it **larger** rather then smaller.  For my situation, I scale factor of 1.5 seems to fix the issue.

```
dotspacemacs-default-font '("Source Code Pro"
                               :size 16
                               :weight normal
                               :width normal
                               :powerline-scale 1.5)
```

Comment: thanks for posting this, it helped me, for some reason when I download spacemacs on Lubuntu, I have a "gui" and "shell" emacs application I can choose from and the "shell" one was giving me a really screwy powerline but the font was larger by default.